# How can we draft better profile for CV?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search, recruitment, job-change

I have very poor in English and I don't have idea how to write professional content for my CV so please help.

I am mentioning my profile with dirty English.

**Company:** Sooryen

- Active participant in client communication and wire-frame designing and prototyping.
- With the help of wire-frame and client communication I am collecting the application business requirement.
- With the help of corematrix I am defining the eCommerce project flow.
- As a Front-end Lead I am monitoring the Jr. Developers and review them code

**Company:** Wirefuture

- Monitoring the workflow and code review the task which are completed by other team members.
- Build, implementation, modification and enhancement Rich UI/UX for single and multi-brand eCommerce application(desktop and mobile).
- WordPress theme development, including use of the Thematic framework and Twitter Bootstrap, and generation of Facebook Open Graph objects for use with Get Running's Facebook integration.

**Company:** UniqApp

A range of roles for a series of large clients from UK and USA. Travelling, often being dropped in at the deep end with unfamiliar technologies and new offices.

Jobs ranged from the solo re-engineering of a web application overnight load to working on what was, at the time, the largest project of a Chinese client, with a team of 10+ as team membor.

Comment: Most of this is far too general.  You need to talk about what YOUR role was in the companies,  ost of it sounds like you're saying "a company I worked at did this".  For example saying you worked on a team of 10+ means little, being team lead/ technical authority/ manager of a 10+ team has value.  Also saying things like re-engineering a web app overnight may have some value in specific jobs, but would fill me with dread of a hack piece.  You need to talk more about what you actually did to fix the app, you can say it was done under tight time concerns, but overnight implies a few bugs or hack

Comment: Thanks, Can you look in to that and guide me more about that?

Comment: Sorry, left my psychic hat at home today! I don't know what you've done in your career and if it was obvious from the question we wouldn't have this conversation. I learned as a dev, that someone like a senior dev could be wildly different between companies, so I started saying explicitly what I did in my role, either sentences or bullet paragraphs (- Team lead - task and line management to a team of 5 junior devs etc). then cover key projects and YOUR role on them.

Comment: Hi Shirish, welcome to The Workplace SE. We don't do CV reviews or give general CV advice here, but if you had more specific questions about your CV, then it might work.  Otherwise, there are too many possible answers to match our Q&A format.  See [help/on-topic] and [ask] for details.

Comment: Shirish, since you have enough rep, you might want to jump into [chat] to see if someone is willing to give you some more in-depth guidance than what can be done on the main Q&A site.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to follow on from my comments, when I was a dev I had something like this for my (then) current role:

XXXX ltd

**Development Lead**

Responsible for leading development of four key systems within XXXX.

The role has the following accountabilities:

- Technical Lead – I have the responsibility for the overall design of key systems running within the yyy division.  As part of this I undertake requirements gathering with key clients; create functional and technical designs for the systems; I work with Strategy Architects to ensure systems fit within overall divisional strategy;  I develop roadmaps for longer term planning of each system; I undertake security and risk assessments for code and systems; I create estimates of effort for each development phase;
- Team Leader -  I lead a development team of up to 5 developers (permanent and contract) using Agile/SCRUM techniques, and have also managed offsite and offshore resources as part of larger deliveries;  I provide mentoring and advice on development and career aspects; I work with PMs and developers to ensure timescales are accurate and are met, and that monthly divisional resourcing plans are correct;  I undertake reviews of both coding/ design and complete systems, from a QA aspect and also from a business viability aspect;
- Application Management - I co-ordinate system deployments and updates (including emergency fixes),  managing development team members and infrastructure based colleagues (e.g. DBAs, Windows/ Mainframe support teams);  I co-ordinate 3rd line support of systems: dealing with clients; leading (where necessary) defect investigations; and agreeing and delivering fixes ensuring SLAs for availability and service are met, and minimising system downtime;
- Senior Developer – I have over 14 years development experience of enterprise level systems, developing not only for .Net (ASP.Net and Win Forms within a high availability, clustered environment) but also enterprise SQL Server development; I also have wide experience of application delivery and configuration management, encompassing both source control via SourceSafe and Team Foundation Server and also designing, testing, and implementing deployment packages using Tivoli.

Then talk about specific projects and achievements.

Answer (score 1):

As the Wandering Dev Manager commented, you need to make it specific to you.

When I am selecting CVs to progress to interview I want to know what the candidate did, not their team or their company.

- What did you do in each of those roles
- What did you gain from it
- What challenges did you face
- How did you benefit your team/company
- How did you progress
- What are your aims
- etc

That way I can see the value you bring, possibly where you will fit, and what your expectations are once you are in the team.

Comment: Not personal. Specific to your role and contributions  :)

Comment: good suggestion Jane - I'll edit that

Comment: No problem! "Personal" is your favourite colour, "specific" is what _you_ did ;)